# Declaring a function in C gives error for expected ';', ',' or ')'

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n);

int main()
{
    int m, n;
    do{
        scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
    }while(((m < 1) || (m > 5)) && ((n < 1) || (n > 5)));

    int A[m][n], i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
            scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);

    printf("Second smallest number in the two dimensional array is %d", second_smallest(A[m][n], m, n));

    return 0;
}

int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n){
    int i, j, min, second_min;

    if (A[0][0] > A[0][1]){
        min = A[0][0];
        second_min = A[0][1];
    }
    else{
        min = A[0][1];
        second_min = A[0][0];
    }

    for (int i = 0;i < m; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            if (A[i][j] <= min)
                second_min = min;
                min = A[i][j];
            }
            else if (A[i][j] > second_min){
                second_min = A[i][j];
            }
}
```

I'm writing a function to find the second smallest number in a two dimensional array and I'm having a problem with declaring the function.

It gives me an error to the following lines:
`int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n);`
and
`int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n){`

The error says the following:
`error: expected ';', ',', or ')' before '&' token.`

And one warning for this line:
`printf("Second smallest number in the two dimensional array is %d", second_smallest(A[m][n], m, n));`

Saying:
`warning: implicit declaration of function 'second_smallest'`

Comment: C doesn't have references.

Comment: The warning is because of the first error. It's common in C (and languages derived from C) to have one root error, that causes other errors and/or warnings.

Comment: You will also have other errors (or at least get other errors when you fix the first one): When you declare the `A` argument the variables `m` and `n` are not declared.

Comment: You also don't call the function correctly, instead of passing the array-of-arrays-of-int `A` you pass the single integer value `A[m][n]`, which is also outside the bounds of `A`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define m 4
#define n 3  

int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n);

                                       // WHAT IS M, N ? IN C YOU HAVE TO DECLARE 
                                      // STATIC ARRAY SIZE BEFORE COMPILATION
                                      // DECLARE THEM AS MACROS

int main()

{


int m, n;
do{
    scanf("%d %d", &m, &n);
}while(((m < 1) || (m > 5)) && ((n < 1) || (n > 5)));

int A[m][n], i, j;

for(i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
        scanf("%d", &A[i][j]);

printf("Second smallest number in the two dimensional array is %d",   second_smallest(A[m][n], m, n));

 return 0;
}

int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n){

int i, j, min, second_min;

if (A[0][0] > A[0][1]){
    min = A[0][0];
    second_min = A[0][1];
}
else{
    min = A[0][1];
    second_min = A[0][0];
}

for (int i = 0;i < m; i++)    // SOME BRACKETS MISMATCH AFTER THIS , CHECK IT.
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (A[i][j] <= min)
            second_min = min;
            min = A[i][j];
        }
        else if (A[i][j] > second_min){
            second_min = A[i][j];
        }
}
```

1. Declare size of array before using them anywhere, if you dont know size, take a pointer as a function parameter and calculate its size using sizeof() operator.

2.Check brackets in your code; The error you have is of a mismatching number of brackets.

Comment: I think explaining what changes you have done and why are they needed will help OP to understand the answer. And yes **indentation does matters**.

Answer (score 1):

First problem with your function prototype is parameter `&A[m][n]`. C doesn't allow pass by reference. Your function prototype is wrong

```
int second_smallest(int &A[m][n], m, n);
```

C doesn't allow this type of function prototype.
Another problem is `m` and `n` are not known to compiler when it encounter with `A[m][n]`. 
Change it to

```
int second_smallest(int m, int n,int A[m][n]);
```

After that change the code snippet

```
for (int i = 0;i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (A[i][j] <= min)
            second_min = min;
            min = A[i][j];
        }
        else if (A[i][j] > second_min){
            second_min = A[i][j];
        }
```

to

```
for (int i = 0;i < m; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        if (A[i][j] <= min){
            second_min = min;
            min = A[i][j];
         }
        else if (A[i][j] > second_min){
            second_min = A[i][j];
        }
     } 
 }
```